# Windows 11 - ENV VAR will not expand, change its name and it will expand - in PATH

Tags: php, environment-variables, windows-11

For reasons not in scope to this question...

I have a ENV VAR: php_root  ->  C:\php
I have another:   php       -> %php_root%\php-8.1
I have %php% in my PATH var

I run "php -v"...

```
'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I run this:

```
for %I in (%PATH%) do @echo %I
```

This expands everything BUT, it gives me this:

```
   C:\php
   %php%
```

So it expands "php_root" but not "php"

I change "php" to (anything other string you like) "mine" (for example), update PATH, and everything works just fine.

```
   C:\php
   C:\php\php-8.1
```

And "php -v" returns:

```
   PHP 8.1.9 (cli) (built: Aug  2 2022 14:17:26) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
```

Also, if I don't use %php_root% in %php%, just give it the full path, it works as well.

Using a VAR in a ENV VAR works in every other case I'm defining.

I have a ENV VAR: php_root  ->  C:\php
I have another:   php       -> %php_root%\php-8.1
I have %php% in my PATH var

I run this:

```
for %I in (%PATH%) do @echo %I
```

I expect this:

```
   C:\php
   C:\php\php-8.1
```

I get this

```
   C:\php
   %php%
```

I run this:

```
   php -v
```

I get this:

```
'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I've restarted PC
I close and open new CMD windows each time I cahge ENV VAR vars

PS: This works fine on everyother windows 11 PC I can get my hands on.